# Problem creating many matrices of random numbers

Tags: r

I want to make a 3x3 matrix with numbers drawn from uniform distribution on the interval [0,1]. And I want to do this 1000 times.

I currently do this:

```
D <- replicate(3, runif(3, 0, 1), simplify=TRUE) 
#This makes a 3x3 matrix with random numbers from
#uniform normal distribution on interval [0,1]

rep(D,times=1000)
```

but that command creates a list containing 9000 numbers, instead of 1000 3x3 matrices. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `lapply`, we can create a list of length 1000, where each element of the list is a desired 3x3 matrix:

```
set.seed(1234)
list_of_mats <- lapply(1:1000, function(x) matrix(runif(9), 3, 3))
```

For example, the eighth matrix is:

```
list_of_mats[[8]]
#           [,1]       [,2]      [,3]
#[1,] 0.01374994 0.30809476 0.5645698
#[2,] 0.23902573 0.50854757 0.1214802
#[3,] 0.70649462 0.05164662 0.8928364
```